# Pandas dataframe row operation within a group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with information about a stock that looks like this:

| Product ID | Initial stock | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 5 | -2 |
| a1 | 5 | -1 |
| a1 | 5 | 7 |
| a2 | 10 | 2 |
| a2 | 10 | -6 |
| b1 | 14 | -9 |
| b1 | 14 | 11 |

Each row represents a purchase/sale of a certain product. I want to add a new column to know the current stock of the product. The first row of every product should be: `Current stock = Inital stock + Quantity` and the next ones: `Current stock[i] = Current stock[i-1] + Quantity[i]`

| Product ID | Initial stock | Quantity | Current stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 5 | -2 | 3 |
| a1 | 5 | -1 | 2 |
| a1 | 5 | 7 | 9 |
| a2 | 10 | 2 | 12 |
| a2 | 10 | -6 | 6 |
| b1 | 14 | -9 | 5 |
| b1 | 14 | 11 | 16 |

In Excel is quite easy, but how would you do it using Pandas? I've tried grouping by Product ID, but I don't know how to introduce the condition of "the first row of every product"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) of the quantity and [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)tract it from the Initial stock :

```
df['Current stock'] = (df['Initial stock']
                         .add(df.groupby('Product ID')['Quantity'].cumsum())
                       )
```

output:

```
  Product ID  Initial stock  Quantity  Current stock
0         a1              5        -2              3
1         a1              5        -1              2
2         a1              5         7              9
3         a2             10         2             12
4         a2             10        -6              6
5         b1             14        -9              5
6         b1             14        11             16
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! I didn't think about cumsum

Comment: @cmoreno98 it's a very useful function in pandas